# Oracle - extract value from certain column from pipe-delimited table stored in CLOB

Tags: oracle, clob

I have table RAW_DATA with multiple columns and one of them is CLOB column which stores pipe-delimited table. This table always has two rows - headers row and data row.

See example below:

```
ACCOUNT|ACCRUED_INTEREST|ID|TRADE_DATE
2425|13566.58|2232323|04/14/2021
```

In my SELECT query I want to pick values stored in some of the columns in CLOB, for example ACCRUED_INTEREST.

How to do this? I tried playing with REGEXP_REPLACE and XMLTABLE, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The one and only idea that came into my mind is to just use substring and specify start and stop points

```
select substr(t.clob_col, instr(t.clob_col, '|', 40) + 1, instr(t.clob_col, '|', 40, 2) - instr(t.clob_col, '|', 40, 1) - 1) accrued_interest 
  from raw_data t
```

1. "instr(t.clob_col, '|', 40)" - looks for first occurency of "|" starting from 40-th symbol of the line to skip the heading
2. "instr(t.clob_col, '|', 40, 2)" - look for second occurency of "|" starting from 40-th symbol

Comment: This is great, works like a charm. I added TO_CHAR at the beginning of it, so TOAD now displays data, otherwise I had to double click on it. I will do some testing to check performance impact, but it does exactly what I wanted. Thank you!